# Wordpress Portfolio changes using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added project-types to my website portfolio https://littleseabear.com/portfolio but it lists all possible tags, and not the tags directly linked to the portfolio.

For example, Cast should only be film, screenplay and work in progress, while When the Boys Come Home should be Radio and Produced.

Here is my code:

```
    $taxonomy = 'jetpack-portfolio-type'  ;
    $tax_terms = get_terms( 'jetpack-portfolio-type'  );


if( is_archive() || is_home() || is_front_page() ){
?>
    <div class="post-wrapper">
<?php 
    infinity_news_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
<div class="post-thumbnail"> 
<?php

                foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
                echo '<a class="filter" href="/project-type/'. $tax_term->slug.'">' . $tax_term->name .'</a>, ';
                }
    ?>
    <div class="article-details <?php if( is_single() ){ echo 'single-article-details'; } ?>">
```

Also... is there a way to get rid of the commas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_terms` retrieves all available tags, not only the ones associated to the current post. Instead, modify the `get_terms` line at the top like so:

```
    $taxonomy = 'jetpack-portfolio-type'  ;
    $tax_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
```

This will collect terms of the `$taxonomy` associated to the current post.

**Edit:**
I missed the question about the commas. To totally get rid of those, you can just remove them from the output:

```
                foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
                echo '<a class="filter" href="/project-type/'. $tax_term->slug.'">' . $tax_term->name .'</a> ';
                }
```

I removed the `,` right behind the closing `</a>`, so it will now only be separated by whitespaces. If you want to have a special separator only between items, you can achieve this like so:

```
                $separator = ''; // initialize empty
                foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
                  echo $separator.'<a class="filter" href="/project-type/'. $tax_term->slug.'">' . $tax_term->name .'</a>';
                  if (empty($separator)) {
                    // Choose a custom separator HERE:
                    $separator = ', ';
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that worked. Do you know how I can get rid of the commas? :)